# Export django models as an image in python3

Tags: django, python-3.x

I would like to export my django models as a graph picture , but graph models from django extensions seems to be broken in python3.

Any idea on how to do that in an other way ?

Thanks

Comment: http://freecode.com/projects/schemaspy does something similar.